# Regular Expression Word Matching with Certain Length and without Numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match following string in Python.

```
100xyz, inc. provides information services aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.
```

I expect the matching result as follows:

```
inc provide information services
```

I used [a-z]{3,15} and got

```
xyz inc provide information services aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa
```

How can I achieve the result I want?

Comment: what function did you use to do the match?

Comment: how do you know where the useful info ends and the bad characters a the end of the string begin ?

Comment: `re.findall(r'\b[a-z]{3,15}\b', s)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How to revise your code to exclude words including three consecutive characters, such as 'aaa'?

Comment: `[x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'\b(?![a-z]*([a-z])\1{2})[a-z]{3,15}\b', s)]`

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew! Very much appreciate your help!!!